# Random Average Number Not Working in Java

Tags: java, average

I need to find the average of random numbers (1-9) and then find the amount of random numbers that are above the average.

I found the average and I tried to find amount of numbers above the average but it keeps giving me the wrong answer.

```
public class AverageRandom{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("n? ");
        int amount = sc.nextInt();

        Random randNo = new Random();
        double sum = 0;
        int max = 9;
        double average = 0;
        int above;
        above = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            int next = randNo.nextInt(max) +1;
            System.out.print(next + " ");

            sum += next;
            average = sum/amount;

            if(next > average){
                above++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nAverage = " + average);
        System.out.print("Number of values above the average = " + above + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is a little bit wrong. How do you expect to know what the average is until you looked at all the numbers? You can't for obvious reasons. So you need to first loop over all entered numbers to determine the average. Once you have your average you can then look at your numbers again and see which ones are above/below the average. What you are currently doing by checking if a number is above/below average befor you are even finished calculating your average can't work.

Comment: "I found the average", print the `average` value on each iteration. You will find out what's wrong

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS So i took the if statement out of the for loop. But now I can't use the num since its only initialised inside the for loop. And I tried making it a global variable but it didn't work either. So how should I find the amount of numbers above the average?

Comment: You need to save the random numbers that are entered/created somewhere in a variable. use an Array, a List, a Set or whatever data structure you want to.

Comment: What @OHGODSPIDERS means is that you need to create an `int[]` with length `amount` and store the *generated* random numbers in that array, so you can iterate through them again *after* calculating the average.

Comment: @Andreas Should I create it inside or outside the for loop?

Comment: @JustTryingToCode If you create it *inside* the loop, you can't use it *after* the loop. If you create it inside the loop, how can it hold *all* the values from each iteration of the loop. If you create it inside the loop, why would it need to have a length of `amount`? If you create it inside the loop, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 2 loops and an array to store the values:

```
public class AverageRandom{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("n? ");
    int amount = sc.nextInt();

    Random randNo = new Random();
    double sum = 0;
    int max = 9;
    double average = 0;

    int[] array = new int[amount]; // define an array of size 'amount'

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        array[i] = randNo.nextInt(max) + 1; // fill the array

        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

        sum += array[i];
    }
    average = sum/array.length; // you can also calculate the average inside the loop

    int above = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // iterate the array (your random values)
        if(array[i] > average){
            above++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nAverage = " + average);
    System.out.print("Number of values above the average = " + above + "\n");
 }
}
```